# Multi-geocoder Yandex

Tags: yandex-maps-api

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('./db');
var MultiGeocoder = require('multi-geocoder');
var geocoder = new MultiGeocoder({ provider: 'yandex-cache', coordorder: 'latlong' }),
    provider = geocoder.getProvider();

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    //var dataJSON = Object.keys(req.body);
    //var points = JSON.parse(dataJSON);
    var points = req.body;
    points.length;
    var a = 0;
    provider.getText = function (point) {
        var address = point.Адрес;
        a = a + 1;
        console.log("count: ",a);
        return address;
    };               
geocoder.geocode(points)
        .then(function (results) { 
            console.log(results); 
            res.send(results);
        })
        .fail(function (err) {
            throw err;
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Почему количество адресов, возвращаемых в метод getText превышает длину исходного массива в 2-3 раза?
При геокодировании массива в 5000 адресов начинают валиться ошибки "Too many requests". У сервиса геокодирования есть ограничение на количество обращений?

Comment: [Условия использования API Яндекс.Карт](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/terms/index-docpage/): "Для бесплатной версии API лимит составляет 25 000 запросов в сутки."

Comment: Я в курсе за 25000. Почему данное сообщение появляется при 5000?

Comment: Вы можете проверить количество запросов по вашему api-ключу в [Кабинете разработчика](https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/).

Comment: Количество запросов в Кабинете разработчика не меняется, потому что я не использую API-key (точнее не использовал). Т.к. модуль multi-geocoder позволяет не использовать ключ

Comment: Сейчас попробовал пример с использованием ключа https://github.com/dimik/node-multi-geocoder Ничего не поменялось. На вход подаю массив из 5000 адресов. Счетчик обращений к геокодеру (который в коде), насчитал 12700 обращений.

Comment: Вам следует задать этот вопрос напрямую в техподдержку с указанием ключа, там разберутся и дадут ответ.